# iOS Content from horizontal to vertical with animation and vice-versa

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Can we achieve this by `UIStackView` as initially its **vertical axis** then eventually it will be **horizontal axis** and vice-versa?

If using `NSAutoLayout`, how this can be done?

Need help if anyone can provide me source of example or any hint here will be helpful.

[I found this Android library](https://github.com/florent37/ExpectAnim/)

[image: Need animation like this]

Comment: Check this https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/twitterprofilepage

Comment: @JonSnow : here my requirement is more complicated. But I want to say thank you for hint +1

Comment: as per my thinking UIStackView won't helpful here I can observe size changes for for horizontal axis with animation

Comment: "Can we achieve this by UIStackView as initially its vertical axis then eventually it will be horizontal axis" is a question ?

Comment: Why do you think UIStackView won’t work? You just change the axis from vertical to horizontal. That’s pretty much it.

Comment: you can acheive it by just increasing the vertical content hugging priority of the elements in the stack vie in ascending order from left to right. And make oulet for stackview height constraint, then by using viewWith animation function toggle the height of the stack view. Trigger this function in scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Apparently, you know nothing @JonSnow! `UIStackViews` do help, see answer below. (No offense, nothing personal, had to do it)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I don't mind your words , One is never capable to know each and every thing ,There is many things that you might not know and same apply to me and others too, So for me it is very fine with that I learnt New thing :) Thankyou

Comment: Man I didn’t even meant that. I just said that because you were wrong about that and your name is Jon Snow. Like GoT, you know? 

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Please don't take me wrong !! , I am very happy to admit my mistakes !! and it is not shameful for me , As I told you my first goal is to learn something new and that what i got !! Thank - you  for understanding me:-]

Comment: @JonSnow... dude. Go watch Game of Thrones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update Answer**

Thanks to  @Fogmeister

Frist I make two StackViews
one hold namelable and profileImage

and bigStackView hold first stackView and followButton

[image]

**constraints like this**

**BigStackView:**

[image]

the reason why I add 20 points on left and right because if I make it 0 the follow button will be close to edge of screen!

**StackView:**
you don't need to add constraint on this stackView

**profileImage:**

[image]

**NameLable:**

[image]

**FollowImage:**

[image]

and then I make both of them equal spacing with 5 spacing when scrolling down

but when scrolling up the spacing of StackView will be 15 so the profile image will be far of nameLable (this is the reason why I add two stackViews so I can control spacing)

and also add hight constraint to stackView with 160 point 
and change it to 100 point when scrolling up

the code will become like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var bigStackView: UIStackView!

    @IBOutlet weak var StackView: UIStackView!

    @IBOutlet weak var StackViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var progileHight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var profileWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!



    var rowsNames = ["Row 0", "Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5",
                  "Row 6", "Row 7", "Row 8", "Row 9", "Row 10", "Row 11",
                  "Row 12", "Row 13", "Row 14", "Row 15", "Row 16", "Row 17",
                  "Row 18", "Row 19", "Row 20", "Row 21", "Row 22", "Row 23",
                  "Row 24", "Row 25", "Row 26", "Row 27", "Row 28", "Row 29", "Row 20"]




    // we set a variable to hold the contentOffSet before scroll view scrolls
    var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowsNames.count

    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = rowsNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



    // this delegate is called when the scrollView (i.e your UITableView) will start scrolling
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

    // while scrolling this delegate is being called so you may now check which direction your scrollView is being scrolled to
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // moved to top


                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                                   animations: {


// Change Hight and Witdh of profileImage (make it smaller)

                                    self.progileHight.constant = 50
                                    self.profileWidth.constant = 50

                self.bigStackView.axis = .horizontal

                                    self.StackView.axis = .horizontal

                                    // Change spacing between profileImage and nameLable
                                    self.StackView.spacing = 15

                                    // Make BigStackView Smaller
                                    self.StackViewHight.constant = 100



                                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


                    })



        } else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // moved to bottom

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           animations: {


                            // return Hight and Witdh of profileImage to its orginal size

                            self.progileHight.constant = 100
                            self.profileWidth.constant = 100


                            self.bigStackView.axis = .vertical

                            self.StackView.axis = .vertical

                            // return spacing between profileImage and nameLable to the orginal space
                            self.StackView.spacing = 5

                            // return BigStackView to its orginal size 
                            self.StackViewHight.constant = 160


           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                             })

        } else {
            // didn't move
        }
    }







}
```

**The result will be :**

[image]

**Old Answer :**

I don't think you can achieve this by UIStackView

but it's very easy to do it with UIView

frist make your StoryBoard like this

[image]

[image]

then add constraints

**UIView :**

[image]

**profileImage:**

[image]

**nameLable:**

[image]

**followButton:**

[image]

I did tested on every iPhone device and with iPad , the constraint doesn't break

then you just need to use UIView.animate

and move items around

the code will be like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    var rowsNames = ["Row 0", "Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5",
                  "Row 6", "Row 7", "Row 8", "Row 9", "Row 10", "Row 11",
                  "Row 12", "Row 13", "Row 14", "Row 15", "Row 16", "Row 17",
                  "Row 18", "Row 19", "Row 20", "Row 21", "Row 22", "Row 23",
                  "Row 24", "Row 25", "Row 26", "Row 27", "Row 28", "Row 29", "Row 20"]


    @IBOutlet weak var squareView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var hightView: NSLayoutConstraint!



    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLable: UILabel!

    // we set a variable to hold the contentOffSet before scroll view scrolls
    var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowsNames.count

    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = rowsNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



    // this delegate is called when the scrollView (i.e your UITableView) will start scrolling
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

    // while scrolling this delegate is being called so you may now check which direction your scrollView is being scrolled to
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // moved to top

                    self.hightView.constant = 100


                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                                   animations: {


                 self.profileImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX:-150, y: -15).scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)


                 self.followButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX:130, y: -110)

              self.nameLable.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX:-95, y: -80)


                                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


                    })



        } else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            // moved to bottom

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           animations: {

            self.hightView.constant = 206
            self.profileImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.followButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.nameLable.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                             })

        } else {
            // didn't move
        }
    }







}
```

what I did was detect if user scrolling up or down

when it scrolling up

I change the hight of the UIView and also 
change the position of ProfileImage and make it smaller by half its size
then change the namaLable and also the followButton

and when it scrolling down 
I return the hight size to original size
and return the rest views to its original size using

```
CGAffineTransform.identity
```

The result is

[image]

I hope this solution is usual for you

Comment: This is possible with StackView. It is literally the case of animating the `axis`. One line of code. (Well, maybe a couple lines)

Comment: I find it ridiculous that people are just like "I need this, do it for me" and it's just your regular everyday task that takes 30 mins max.

Comment: Is your constraints are breaking ? , If you don't mind could you please show me your applied  constraints + 1 for you

Comment: @JonSnow you can’t animate like this when using AutoLayout. The constraints will break. To animate using AutoLayout you have to animate the constraints themselves. Btw... it is a really bad idea to follow this answer. Using CGRect like this is really not recommended. You should always be looking to use AutoLayout.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes That's why I asked   
**Is your constraints are breaking ?** Because GIF shows output achieved but it is very important that constraints never break !!! Thank you

Comment: @JonSnow it’s not my answer. My answer is the other one. :-)

Comment: @JonSnow for me it doesn't break , I tested it on every devices , anyway I updated my answer with my constraints and also with using StackView

Comment: @Basil : Can you provide whole solution as I am missing some piece

Comment: @PareshNavadiya I updated my answer and give more details , and fix the issue with profileImage now it's look good , if there is anything else missing tell me

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd add an answer using `UIStackView` as you seem to have dismissed it without trying it.

I added a gist here with all the code. The code is a bit dodgy as 95% of it is setting up the Playground page and views etc...

https://gist.github.com/oliver-foggin/7ef9e2b7f77b733ea0afb782d7c7d7e0

It took me about 10 minutes in total.

Looking at your animation I noticed that there are only three things changing. The size of the round view, the corner radius of the round view, and the axis of the layout (vertical/horizontal).

This is reflected in the animation code used in my example...

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    roundViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60
    roundView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
}
```

This results in the following animation (which can be tweaked to improve it but I don't have much time to write this)...

[image]

Updated the code slightly to try to improve the animation...

```
stackView.axis = .horizontal
roundViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

New animation...
[image]

The corner radius doesn't animate properly on a layer. That is because I'm using a UIView and not a UIImageView like in your original. With a UIImageView you would not bother changing the corner radius like I'm doing. Just use a rounded image instead.

Comment: I find it ridiculous that people are just like "I need this, do it for me" and it's just your regular everyday task that takes 30 mins max.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth yup. It’s a wonder I was able to work any of this out myself. How did we learn anything before StackOverflow? Lol! TBH. Looking at it now I should’ve asked the OP to try it and come back when they were stuck. I must’ve been feeling generous. 

Comment: `UIView.Animate` cannot animate Layer (`layer.cornerRadius`) , it's better to change `cornerRadius` on Viewdidload so since beginning will be cycle  or use **CABasicAnimation** to animate cornerRadius . these will fix laggy  animate on circle UIView